# Google Chrome for Android Remote Debugging - "localhost:9222" Not Available

Tags: android, google-chrome, remote-debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm following the steps to enable remote debugging (https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging). When I reach step 4, Chrome for Desktop returns with "This webpage is not available".

"Enable USB Web Debugging" is checked in Chrome for Android.

"USB Debugging" is enabled on my device (rooted Nexus S, CM9).

The "adb devices" command return with, "*device number* device".

The "adb forward..." command returns with:
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

I'm running the latest ADB on Windows 7, cmd as Administrator.

Comment: have you tried the `adb forward` after the emulator successfully started?

Comment: Yes, I ran the command again. Same result. I switched to the stock rom (4.0.4) just to rule out CM9. Same result.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found that I had to have USB debugging enabled on Chrome and on my device.

1. Chrome for Mobile - Settings > Developer Tools > [x] Enable USB Web debugging
2. Device - Settings > Developer options >  [x] USB debugging
3. Connect Device to Computer
4. Enable port forwarding on Computer

   C:\adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
5. Go to `http://localhost:9222` in Chrome for Computer

Comment: @enduro's steps are the way to go. There's a video on youtube (featured in google) showing the steps in the wrong order.

Comment: Many thanks! I forgot to enable USB Web debugging on my device. Made my day :)

Comment: This answer is out of date, it seems. There aren't developer tools for mobile chrome anymore. Instead you go to `chrome:inspect` on your desktop chrome.

Comment: unable to find the option 1 in my device(Motoe2 6.0.1)

Answer (score 4):

Can you please provide the version of Chrome on Android you are using? Open "about:version" URL and please provide values of "Google Chrome" an "Application" fields.

And can you please check the following -- after you turn on USB Web debugging (step 2 of the doc), what this sequence of commands outputs to you:

```
adb root
adb shell cat /proc/net/unix | grep chrome_devtools_remote
```

(The idea is to check, if the remote debugging socket opens on the device after you turn on USB Web debugging)

Comment: Chrome 19.0.1084.30 (Official Build 132762) beta-m

I don't see an "application" line. Maybe the startup options will be useful:

--flag-switches-begin --enable-experimental-extension-apis --enable-sync-tabs --flag-switches-end --flag-switches-begin --enable-experimental-extension-apis --enable-sync-tabs --flag-switches-end

"adb root" returns:
adbd cannot run as root in production builds

"adb shell..." doesn't work as I'm on Windows 7.

I've switched back to the stock rom (4.0.4) just to rule out CM9. It seems like it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: I'm not familiar with all this command line stuff, but isn't `grep` a linux command? (just wondering, cause I've got Win7 too and it doesn't know this command)

Comment: @Peter grep is a linux command, you can get it in Cygwin (highly recommended) or you can use the retarded windows version named find where the command would be `adb shell cat /proc/net/unix | find "chrome_devtools_remote"`.  The quotes are NOT optional even though there are no spaces, hence the "retarded" comment.

Answer (score 4):

Have you changed your localhost at all?
If so then try **127.0.0.1:9222** instead of **localhost:9222**.

Answer (score 2):

I had two really dumb problems preventing me from doing this correctly, maybe my experience will help.

1: The "adb forward..." from the most voted-up comment on the YouTube channel explaining how to do it contains a few weird characters (https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=s4zpL4VBbuU). If, like me, you pasted it in cmd without double-checking, the server will start without an error, but the service won't work properly. Make sure you're using this line with your path to adb

```
adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

2: ESET NOD32 Antivirus has this thing called HIPS (Host-Based Intrusion Prevention System), and it doesn't like you messing around with `localhost:####`

http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2950

Maybe your Antivirus software has something similar that can be deactivated?

Hope this helps someone ^_^

Comment: And I sat there with the copied command and wondering why it doesn't work ... :/ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You no longer need to fuss with adb, downloads or command lines. With Chrome v41 (canary), I just plugged in the phone, pointed the browser to chrome://inspect, then hit the "inspect" link below my device, and the debug window opened and worked. (Enable USB debugging in the developer options on the phone)

I add that this worked first time, whereas my efforts with Chrome v39 plus the platform tools sdk, adb and the rest, had still not given fruit after 6 hours or so.

Answer (score 0):

The remote debugging features requires a small check. The USB debugging features should be rather turned off and only the option for `USB Debugging` under chrome (android) settings should be checked.

Also, run the adb forward command twice(the complete command with specific arguments).

Comment: with USB debugging features off adb doesn't even recognize my mobile phone, why would I want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the Chrome Browser for Android in your phone. And then navigate again in your Desktop to localhost:9222
Android Remote Debugging just works with the mobile Chrome browser. Some users think that the native Android browser is Chrome but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

C:\adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote

helped me to find the cause on my system. It was having multiple devices connected. After removing all the devices, and connected only one required device resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. I've been looking for one last day same command in the tutorial

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/contributing-legacy

"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-first-run --user-data-dir=C:\Users\%username%\chrome-dev-profile http://localhost:11002#http://localhost:8000/front_end/inspector.html

Then I can use localhost: 9222 on the browser.

Right now I would like to comment on the answer to help someone.