# Debug mobile app from Chrome - localhost not resolved

Tags: android, debugging, mobile, localhost, adb

I remember with another phone I was able to debug my local website dev, now there is a problem preventing me to open localhost in my mobile and cannot find how.

Looking at:
[Google Chrome for Android Remote Debugging - "localhost:9222" Not Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212256/google-chrome-for-android-remote-debugging-localhost9222-not-available)

my phone is connected, on localhost:9222 I can see a list of tabs.

I can access tabs loading site from remote, but cannot load my localhost.

In one case, error displayed: 
408 - Timeout.

On another , simply chrome display site is not reachable.
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I tried both with port-forward enabled as well as not (if enabled, listening to 8081, 8080).

Phone is connected via USB but seems cannot reach my localhost address of the laptop, still on same wifi spot.

*EDITED*

> I remember with another phone I was able to debug my local website
>   dev, now there is a problem preventing me to open localhost in my
>   mobile and cannot find how.

I was doing with Bonjour- the "Bonjour host" is the name Mac assign to your user machine user.local. I was able to connect former android host, but now it cannot be solved anymore unless of IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two devices should be on the same network and it won't be localhost in that case, but you have to replace localhost with the IP of the server PC!

So instead of `localhost:9222`, it would be `192.168.1.10:9222` giving that `192.168.1.10` is your IP address!

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I am using an alias hostname to make it searchable - like `http://foo.local/~user/` I m "quite  sure" it was resolved on other moblile (not `localhost`, but the alias to make it searchable in the same network). Your answer is correct, I'll mark it correct, and make me thing if my "quite sure" is not a faulty memory. But, for the sake of being correct - could you explain possible reasons of why alias is not resolved ?

Comment: @user305883 the alias is only available to the system it's written on except maybe if it's some kind of a DNS server, so if you have root to your Android phone then you can write the alias there `/system/etc/hosts`, or I believe there are some other methods like a DNS server for example!